# RSpec Catch Validation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

I have a model that validates name and terms acceptance

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 50 }, on: :update

  validates_acceptance_of :agreed_to_terms, on: :update
```

I have written a simple test

```
  it 'redirects back if there is missing info' do
    post "/product/1", {:name => "john"}

    expect(ActiveRecord).to raise_error(StatementInvalid)
  end
```

I can't seem to catch the error.

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:
```

Comment: Are you sure that this error is actually raised? Typically validations simply cause the model to return `false` for `valid?`.

Comment: Validations won't cause that error to be raised (when using `save` ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid is raised

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
it 'redirects back if there is missing info' do
  expect {
    post "/product/1", {:name => "john"}
  }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
end
```

Comment: But then if I remove the validation, it still passes @Vimsha

Answer (score 0):

`expect() raise_error` means the code in () raise an error, clearly when you call ActiveRecord won't trigger it.

You can try like this.

```
expect{
    post "/product/1", {:name => "john"}
 }.to raise_error(StatementInvalid)
```

Btw, i don't think to test a model validations in controller is a good idea.

Comment: But then if I remove the validation, it still passes @jerrytao

Comment: You need to give more informations, Like which columns failed constraint or more details about your model. Also the params in controller.